# jQuery - Does not work in Facebook iFrame

Tags: jquery, facebook, internet-explorer-9

I developed a landing page in facebook and use jQuery to show and hide certain text fields. Now this works great in Firefox, but not in IE 9. I have no idea how this can happen. I have an index.php and there I say

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.overlabel.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("label.overlabel1").overlabel();
        $("label.overlabel2").overlabel();
        $("label.overlabel3").overlabel();
        $("input").show();
    });
 </script>
```

As I said, it works in Firefox, but not in IE.

I'd be happy for every help.

Thanks in advance,

enne

EDIT: Here is some code that works in Firefox but not in IE. It just puts the word "hello" in the input field:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>JVP-Gewinnspiel</title>
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
     <style type="text/css">
         #overlay {width:10px; height:10px; background-color:#F00;}
     </style>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>

<body>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#vn").val("hello");
     });
</script>


  <div id = "main">
     <div class="inputField">
       <label for="vn" class="overlabel1">Vorname</label>
       <input name="vn" id="vn" type="text"  />
      </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you get any javascript errors?

Comment: have you checked for javascript warnings in firebug?

Comment: where is the `input` variable declared?  or is that a typo?

Comment: Code looks valid, is your HTML valid?

Comment: Well, I replaced the complete code with some very basic code that works on my local machine, but as soon as I upload it and use it on facebook, it doesn't work there.

Comment: shouldn't the src of the JS be pointing to an absolute url?

Comment: You don't have to use absolute URLs. Did you test that page, uploaded, but outside of Facebook iFrame ?

Are "jquery" and jquery.overlabel available on your server ?

Comment: Yes they are both. I reduced the code very much, please see my edit above.

Comment: Ok, I think the solution is to define the HTML-Code BEFORE the javascript-code. As soon as I do so, it works in IE.

Comment: does using the f12 ie developer tools script debugging turn anything up?

Comment: no, actually everything seems to work fine also during debugging.